# Java versus Cython memory efficiency

Tags: java, performance

I am comparing a custom java Random Forest implementation to the SciKit implementation that takes advantage of Cython. The algorithms are very similar and I have tested them on the same datasets. The java implementation requires far more memory than Python. I know this could be caused by a number of things but I wanted to get a handle on how much of it may be the underlying C versus Java space efficiency. Assuming both algorithms are written optimally or at least mostly optimal, how much different could I expect there to be in memory usage?

Comment: When you say 'requires' do you mean that if you set the max heap size around what the python implementation is using, you get out of memory errors?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: It would help if you could quantify the difference in memory usage.  e.g. is it 100% more?

Comment: On the order of about 500% more memory consumption by Java implementation than by Cython.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this using the "time" command if you are on Linux or Mac. This will allow you to see how long it takes for each of your programs (Java, Python, C) to run. If you want to test memory efficiency, you could use a debugger (such as gdb for C) and step through the code to see exactly what is happening "under the hood". I think when it really comes down to it, you need to run some benchmark tests.

What I have found is sometimes Java will run faster than C in some situations, but sometimes C will have better memory usage and optimization. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect an apples to apples Java implementation to be comparable to the Python version.  As you say, there are many factors here but if you are seeing a large difference in memory usage, the most likely reason is that it's something about the way the Java implementation is written.

My experience is that usually when a Java program uses more memory than it should, the reason is that the application is doing something like:

1. take input record one at a time and put it into a collection
2. process each record from the collection one at a time

In other words, it's nothing fundamental about Java, it's about the design of the application in that it's storing large amounts of data in the heap unnecessarily.

At 500% more memory, it's highly unlikely this is inherent to Java.  That would mean that Java would have 5 bytes of overhead for every byte used in the algorithm.  If that were reality, Java would be extremely expensive.  It wouldn't really be viable to run much of the cloud software running on google or AWS and it wouldn't make any sense for Android.  Without the source, there isn't much more that anyone can tell you about why you are seeing this.

The only thing I can think other than just holding on to things that aren't needed is something like using 64-bits to hold a single byte when the Cython is putting 8 bytes in each word.  If this were the case, it's something you could fix in the Java version, though.

Comment: Just to clarify its Cython not Python. Meaning we're comparing efficiency of C code with Java code.

Comment: @user123959 According to the main page at cython.org, "The Cython language is a superset of the Python language."  Many languages are compiled to C and Java has been also.  The 'efficiency' of the generated C is dependent on the compiler.  It isn't really the case that you are just comparing C to Java.  It's possible there are some tricks that allow Cython to use less memory than Java but I think it's more likely that it's how the Java code is written.